# Use Regex To Get String

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve string 'ABCD' from following HTML code using regex

```
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Arial Narrow, serif"><FONT SIZE=2 STYLE="font-size: 9pt"><I>-
        / ABCD</I></FONT></FONT></P>
```

I am using regex -

```
/I>(.*?)<\/I>
```

But it is not returning any matches.

Comment: regex is no php function. If you want to get something with RegEx, you need "preg_match("your regex")

Comment: You should use a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php) to work with HTML.

Comment: This `HTML` is ancient!

Comment: try this: preg_match('/[A-Z]+/',strip_tags($str),$match),$str is your HTML code

Comment: @Nightmare Why don't you add this as an answer?

Comment: @OlafDietsche probably because of `strip_tags()`.

Comment: No, because there are a lot of dumbasses which complain if your answer doesnt contain at least 100 letters ... ive seen such guys, not kidding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0cm"><FONT FACE="Arial Narrow, serif"><FONT SIZE=2 STYLE="font-size: 9pt"><I>-
        / ABCD</I></FONT></FONT></P>';


preg_match('#I>(.*?)</I>#si',$str,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```